# Trying to use React Hook and Axios to display data from my API but nothing is rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Designer creating my first full-stack app to better understand more complex development concepts. I'm currently unable to get data displayed in the browser from my React app. However, unlike previous roadblocks, I'm not getting an actual error to search, so I'm not exactly sure where I've got a problem.

The client and server seem to load up fine (localhost:3000 and :8000 respectively) but my very simple app.js client doesn't display anything. In the terminal window I do see:

`"Executing (default): SELECT "id", "title", "subtitle", "lyric", "published", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "playlists" AS "playlists"; GET /api/playlists 200 49.085 ms - 463`

So it seems like the GET request might be working, but I'm staring at a blank white screen in the browser. Any help would be appreciated. Happy to provide more info but I'll include the app.js below.

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect }from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ playlists: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios('http://localhost:8000/api/playlists');
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [] );

  return (
    <div>
      All Playlists
       <ul>
        {data.playlists && data.playlists.map(playlist => (
          <li key={playlist.id}>
           {playlist.title}{playlist.subtitle}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is the network request successful, or failing? Does the endpoint return errors? Please check and share what the value of `result` is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set request method in `axios`:

So if it is `GET`:

```
const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/playlists');
```

Comment: Of course! It's still a white screen but now I've got some ACTUAL errors I can work with! Much obliged. Errors for reference below:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/playlists/api/playlists' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:8000/api/playlists/api/playlists net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: So, the problem is `CORS` you have to enable it in your backend.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an CORS issue. I don't know for other languages, but if you're using experss, you can easily rectify it by adding a CORS Middleware.

```
Yarn add CORS
```

And in your index file

```
Const cors = require(`cors`)

//After express initialization

app.use(cors)
```

You can extend the configuration of course, but just doing this will solve your problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have object with array in your initial state value as you can have multiple `useStates` in same component. You can set initial state value to empty array. I would rename `const [data, setData] = useState([]);` to `const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState([])` to make it more readable. Now in your map you can just use:

```
  <ul>
    {playlists.map(playlist => (


        <li key={playlist.title}>
          {playlist.title}
          {playlist.subtitle}
        </li>

    ))}
  </ul>
```

Your whole component would look like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
      'http://localhost:8000/api/playlists'
    );
    setPlaylists(result.data);
  };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      All Playlists
      <ul>
        {playlists.map(playlist => (


            <li key={playlist.title}>
              {playlist.title}
              {playlist.subtitle}
            </li>

        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, This is much cleaner and easier to read. More importantly, it works!